# Pandas Excelwriter, writer.save()

Tags: python-3.x, file, xlsx, saving-data, pandas.excelwriter

Pandas **Excelwriter**, **writer.save()**
the command is saving the file in read-only mode.
Does it have an option to **save the file in write mode**.

Problem: When i am trying to copy the cell values (through python coding) from the file created from writer.save(), its says that the value is **read-only**.
Note: I am working with xlsx files.

Comment: maybe yoou should share some code... we couldn't help if u do not share what you write...technically it is hard to write in read-only mode in pandas if you do not explictily code to sdo o

Answer (score 5):

`writer.save()` is depreciated, use `writer.close()`

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.close.html#pandas.ExcelWriter.close

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33997530)

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't shared the code snippet I don't understand the exact problem. But this code doesn't give any error while reading the data back from XLSX file.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

#Write to XLSX
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

#Read from XLSX
df1 = pd.read_excel('pandas_simple.xlsx')
print(df1)
```